# Rails param for show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used params in a URL for the index page successfully. But, I'm not getting the same success with the show page.

This is what I'm trying to use:

```
def show
  @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])
  @workorder = Workorders.where("wonum = #{params[:wonum]}") if params[:wonum].present?
```

Then I'm trying those URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000/workorders/?wonum='14-21291'
http://localhost:3000/workorder?wonum='14-21291'
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE 1

Rake Routes:

[image]

UPDATE2

What I would really like is this url to work:

```
http://localhost:3000/workorder?wonum='14-21263'
```

Could I add a route to the workorder show function?

Comment: Are you trying to access `show` page with a `link` in your `index` page? show us the view pages?

Comment: this total wrong `"wonum = #{params[:wonum]}"`!!!

Comment: I first want to be able to go to a specific workorder using a URL.  Then I have javascript code using Bootbox to have the user enter the `wonum`.

Comment: Share your `routes` defined for `workorders`.

Comment: @Reddirt just read this just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399467/rails-is-this-query-open-to-sql-injection)

Comment: why do you want to make this (http://localhost:3000/workorder?wonum='14-21263') type of URL for hitting show action when this can be accomplished using (http://localhost:3000/workorder/14-21263). and params[:id] will give 14-21263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need some minor changes and you'll get what you need.

It's important to understand that rails expects route ids to corrospond to database ids like the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/workorder/32'
```

This will save 32 in `params[:id]`

This is the default behavior and you will see this in all the rails beginner examples.
You will run into problems because you are trying to find Work orders by a different field, not id. So you need to change the code in your workorders controller.

Try this:

```
def show
  @workorder = Workorders.where(:wonum, params[:wonum]).first if params[:wonum].present?
  @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id]) if @workorder.nil?
```

The major differences are how I call the where method (this way where add security for you) and trying to find a workorder from the :wonum parameter before trying to find it using the id. I suspect in your attempt, you were getting a record not found, or routing exception because you didn't pass in an id at all in your example url.

With an id:
`http://localhost:3000/workorder?333wonum='14-21263'`

I suggest looking at the sql generated in your rails server window to see what is going on.

You should look at this gem for a cleaner, off the shelf solution to what you're trying to do  -> https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/

Comment: Using your "try this", what would the URL look like? Would it be like this? `http://localhost:3000/workorders/?wonum='14-21263’` THANKS

Comment: I got this to work: `    @workorder = Workorder.where("wonum = #{params[:wonum]}").first if params[:wonum].present?`